# IPython /bin/bash: /bin/bashfile.txt: Permission denied

Tags: ipython

This issue is inside IPython:

1) when i run the following, it works fine

```
for x in range(10):
    !date
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
Tue Jun 12 13:25:18 EDT 2018
```

2) when i want to redirect it into the file, it gives the following error message:

```
for x in range(10):
    !date > ${x}.txt

/bin/bash: /bin/bashfile.txt: Permission denied
```

Im honestly not sure why am i getting that error message. I don't understand it.

Comment: Were you expecting `${x}` to interpolate the current value of the loop counter? That's not how the syntax works.

Comment: you cannot write to `/bin/` as normal user.Use some other path.

Comment: Just following the 'OReilly's Python for Unix and Linux System Administration' -- page 43.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to interpolate the value of the Python variable `x` into a shell command in IPython, [the syntax for that is `$x` or `{x}`, not `${x}`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access). When `x` is `0`, `${x}` expands to `$0`, which the shell then does its own expansion for. Your command should be

```
!date > {x}.txt
```

(It's unlikely that `$0` would have expanded to `/bin/bashfile`, suggesting that you probably didn't actually run the code you posted.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do here, but you're trying to write to a file that you do not have write permission for.

Make a new file and try writing to it and you'll succeed.